# ¿Cómo enviar un mensaje con python-telegram-bot fuera de los handlers?

Tags: python, telegram

Estoy [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.org/) y quiero enviar un mensaje sin esperar a recibir un evento (mensaje, comando, etc.). Intenté esto pero me dice que `job_queue` es `None`.

```
async def saluda(context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await context.bot.sendMessage(context.job.chat_id, text="Estoy vivo")

def main():
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token("TOKEN").build()

    app.job_queue.run_once(saluda, 0, chat_id= ### )

    app.run_polling()
```

¿Cómo debería hacer para recibir el mensaje "Estoy vivo" al ejecutar el script en Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final conseguí hacerlo con la función [`post_init`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.applicationbuilder.html#telegram.ext.ApplicationBuilder.post_init).

```
async def saluda(app: Application) -> None:
    await app.bot.sendMessage(chat_id, text="Estoy vivo")

def main():
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token("TOKEN").post_init(saluda).build()

    app.run_polling()
```